# Geoserver Map Rendering

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

I have done an application with Geoserver for WMS Map rendering. In this application I have made a Dynamic Layer Group concept in which all the layers which I have checked on will be made as a layer group and request will be sent only once instead of single request for each layer. There are totally 89 layers. Another concept I have used in Load balancing. Totally 4 apache tomcat, in which application is in 1st tomcat and other 3 tomcat has geoserver. The WMS requests will flow in 3 geoserver

The following screenshot shows balancing of geoserver map rendering using "apache balance manager"
[image]

Eventhough I have made this many configurations, the getmap requests is very slow and it is not upto expected level. Since this application is going to used by more than 20 users, this speed is not sufficient. Geowebcache is not possible since map data is dynamic. We don't know what layer will be selected by the user.

My Queries :

> I need to tune my application to work for 30 user simultaneously presently i having an HP server with XEON Processor + 4 GB RAM
>
> ANy other peculiar configurations to be made for faster rendering of maps ? If so please suggest me !!

Comment: Have you looked at geowebcache?

Comment: i am using a layer switcher tab that user checked layers are transferred to the geoserver as dynamic layer group soo pre caching is not possible

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to include that information in the question, along with any metrics you've collected.

Comment: I am not convinced from what you have posted that the load is to heavy for geoserver. What are the 30 users using to view the map data?

Comment: Without additional information on the data (format, amount, preprocessing performed) it is impossible to give a meaningful answer.

I would make sure the data is correctly preprocessed (especially raster data), then I would start thinking about using GeoWebCache if your data does not change frequently.

I would also have a look at this presentation for some additional recipes: http://goo.gl/74XUPq

Aside, what you mean by "the Geoserver failed to serve all the layer" what's the error you are getting?